# How do I rename a tab in Workbench?

Tags: tabs, mysql-workbench

When I create a new query tab, it is named "SQL File 1" or similar. I want to rename it to identify them better. Is it possible?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could have named queries tabs registering them.

```
File > Save Script
```

I'm going post the feature request which I find relevant and I think easy to implement.

Answer (score 1):

I was successful when I did this:

1. In MySQL Workbench, click on the tab you want to rename.
2. Go to file > Save Script As.
3. A window will open that gives you a blank space to type in the name you want.
4. Click Save.
5. Your tab will have a new name.

Answer (score 0):

No, this is not possible atm. Please file a feature request (http://bugs.mysql.com) if you want to have that implemented.