# Rename Tab in Mysql Workbench

Tags: mysql-workbench

Can anybody post an explanatory line how to rename a tab in Mysql Workbench 6.2 ?

According to manual the function is there => http://dev.mysql.com/doc/workbench/en/wb-what-is-new-62.html but there is no a single blah how this option should be called.

I have also grepped through http://downloads.mysql.com/docs/workbench-en.html-chapter.tar.gz , the manual states that a tab may be renamed but there is no explanation how.

I have also tried function key F2, contextual menu and I have tried to dig something from the inbuilt functions but no result.

I am using Ubuntu 14.04

Answer (score 8, accepted):

To get the rename option into the contextual menu for an entity relational model has to user select the “MySql Model” tab and right click on the diagram in EER Diagram browser.

There is no contextual option for renaming Sql script tabs, the only way to attribute a specific name to a sql thumb is to save the script to a file.

Comment: The issue with tab renaming was also brought up here => http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21138118/how-do-i-rename-a-tab-in-workbench and is a subject of a feature request.

Answer (score -1):

Huh? Figure 1.7 and the small paragraph above it clearly tell you how you can rename a result set tab. Note: this does not apply to sql editor tabs. You can only rename result set tabs.

Comment: It is stated in the description that documentation mention the renaming option what I am missing here is how do we bring bring up that contextual menu? Right click on the tab has no “Rename” option. Does it in your case?

Comment: What options does it show for you? You right-click on the tab. In the example, you'd right click on the [city 1] tab to rename it from "city 1" to something else.

Comment: Contextual menu has no rename option it is mentioned in the description.

Comment: Look again at figure 1.7 (http://dev.mysql.com/doc/workbench/en/images/wb-pin-results-tab.png). It clearly has a "Rename Tab" entry (result set tabs only, as already mentioned).